# How do I get this mutator to work upon cellEdited?

Tags: tabulator

I'm using Tabulator 3.5 and have a mutator:

```
Tabulator.extendExtension("mutator", "mutators", {
    percentageMutator:function(value, data, type, mutatorParams){

        console.log(mutatorParams);  // sanity check - we'll come back to this!
        console.log(data);  // sanity check - we'll come back to this!
        // code omitted here to perform calculations
        return percentage

        }
    });
```

My constructor object, stripped of all niceties, is as below. Notice that the columns are nested twice. Notice also that I'm using the Django template language to dynamically build the table.

```
    $("#markbook-table").tabulator({
        columns: [
            {title: "First Name", field: "firstname", validator: ["maxLength:50", "string"]},
            {title: "Last Name", field: "lastname", validator: ["maxLength:50", "string"]},
            {   title:"Some grouping",
                columns:[
                    {% for assessment in assessments %}
                        {
                            title: "{{ assessment.name }} (out of {{ assessment.max_mark }})",
                            columns:[
                                {title: "Result", field: "{{ assessment.name }}", editor: "input",},
                                {title: "Mark out of", field: "{{ assessment.name }}_outof"},
                                {title: "weighting", field: "{{ assessment.name }}_weighting"},
                                {title: "%", field: "{{ assessment.name }}_percentage", mutator: "percentageMutator", mutatorParams:{assessmentName: "{{ assessment.name }}"}},
                                },
                                ]
                        },
                    {% endfor %}
                ],
            },
            {% endfor %}
        ],
        data: tableData,
        cellEdited: function(cell) {

            row.update({'Statistics_percentage': false});  // this is the line that fails

            $.ajax({
                // Do ajax magic here to save to database
            });
        },
    })
```

The crux of the matter is that my row.update() doesn't recalculate the % after a change in the result field. The field name 'Statistics_percentage' has been chosen because it fits my current data but I can easily generalise it later.

The console.log(mutatorParams) in the percentageMutator function is the same upon initial construction of the table, and after editing. However, the console.log(data) shows that the row data passed after editing to the percentageMutator function only contains the cell in question and does not contain any data for other cells in the row - hence the calculations fail after editing.

I'm hoping you'd have an idea about how I can force all the row data to be sent to the mutator upon editing. Thanks so much for even reading this far. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the ***mutatorEdit*** and ***mutatorEditParams*** options if you only want the mutator called on edit.

Mutators are only called on a cell if that cells value has been changed, updating the value of other fields in that rows data will not trigger the mutator to be called again as this could lead to unpredictable behaviour *(imagine a mutator that multiplied the incoming value by 1000 as a unit change, if that got called any time any row data got updated, it would quickly corrupt the data)*.

If all you are looking to do is display the value to a user and you don't need to actually store the data, can i suggest that you use a formatter to do this instead, that way you can call the `row.reformat()` function after your update, which will re-run the formatter and recalculate the display value.

Comment: Hi Oli - I'd like the mutator called on both the initial setting of the data, and then again on any edit. It works when I initially set the data, however when I change an adjacent cell, and then force the mutator to work again using row.update({'Statistics_percentage': false});  no row data is passed to the mutator (although the mutatorParams are passed to the mutator function!).

Comment: The formatter option works, although I'd like to be able to sort by the value in the column hence the need for a mutator.

Comment: in that case i would suggest that you just update the value for that column in the same `row.update` call you make in the ***cellEdited*** callback and just abstract the calculation into a function that can be called in the mutator or the cellEdited function.

Comment: after that you can call the `row.reformat()` function to refresh the contents of all cells in the row

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing. I abstract the calculation into a function called in the mutator. When I initially setData the mutator works perfectly - it passes the mutatorParams along with the row data and calculations go smoothly. Later on when an adjacent cell is updated I use the same mutator. The mutatorParams are passed through to the function correctly but the row data is not passed through and the calculations fail.

Comment: I can use a formatter to get around it - but then I also need to write complicated sorter functions which effectively recalculate the whole column. This also means that column calculations effectively need to recalculate the whole table.

Comment: You are missunderdstanding me. if you want to sort then you cannot use the formatter, i am suggesting an alternative solution. DO NOT use the formatter, create a function that does the calculation and call it in the mutator AS WELL AS the cellEdited function, where you can pass the new value of the column in the `row.update` function allong with your current boolean value, that way it will be sortable and the column should display it correctly

Comment: I finally understand what you're saying. I'll let you know how it goes. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Great. Worked a charm!